# HttpClient set up SSLHostnameVerifier and ConnectionManager at the same time

Tags: java, ssl, https

```
Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> reg =RegistryBuilder<ConnectionSocketFactory>create().register("https", new  
SSLConnectionSocketFactory(ctx)).register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
            .build();

    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = newPoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(reg);

    client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(cm)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
            .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
            .build();
```

I use NoopHostnameVerifier because I do not want to verify SSL, but in my ConnectionManager exists essential logic and have not chances forgot ConnectionManager.

The problem is that if I have ConnectionManager and SSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier), I get the following error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

What might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me. I found it [here](http://literatejava.com/networks/ignore-ssl-certificate-errors-apache-httpclient-4-4/).

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm;
        try {
            SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();
            clientBuilder.setSslcontext(sslContext);
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new AllowAllHostnameVerifier());
            Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
                .register("https", sslSocketFactory)
                .build();
            cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException | KeyStoreException e) {
            cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the singleton of `NoopHostnameVerifier`

So change `new NoopHostnameVerifier()` to `NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE`